# get uint8list of network image in flutter web

Tags: flutter, image, dart, video, uint8list

I am trying to get the uint8list from an image/video in the internet. I have fount a solution for that, that works on mobile applications but none for flutter web. Can someone recommend something?

Answer (score -1):

First of all, Share your code so we can understand the full issue.

Describe what have you tried and what type of error the complier gives you.

because I didn't understand the real issue. is it using UInt8List for fetching the image? or the Operation System doesn't support?